# How to concatenate a parameter with a string value in ARM template: Unable to parse template language expression

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I need to concatenate parameters in the ARM template (JSON file), and I have a problem with `"/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent([parameters('id')])}/providers"`. It looks that `[parameters('id')]` is not recognized as a parameter and it is just passed as a text.

I know that it's possible to use `union` expression, but in my case I don't need to just merge two separate parameters (according to my understanding, this is what `union` does). I need to construct a string.

Another option that I have in mind is to do it outside of JSON file, so that I can pass the `"/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent([parameters('id')])}/providers"` as a single parameter. But I find this approach ineffective, because in my ARM template I have 10 similar variables in which I just need to "paste" the value of `id`.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
        ...
        "path": "/subscriptions/@{encodeURIComponent([parameters('id')])}/providers",
        ...
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ARM Template you can use **concat** & **uriComponent** functions to concatenate parameters:

```
"[concat('/subscriptions/', uriComponent(parameters('id')), '/providers')]"
```

In your example, it would be like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
        ...
        "path": "[concat('/subscriptions/', uriComponent(parameters('id')), '/providers')]",
        ...
    }]
}
```

Please refer the documentation for [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array?tabs=json#concat) & [uriComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string?tabs=json#uricomponent).